# Handlebars using variable as part of #each object

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have an object with several keys that I need to loop through. Depending on the page, the key may change and I don't know how to access it. I won't always know the brand value so I need a dynamic way to retrieve it.

```
{{each object.[@root.brand]}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

The variable should return a value something like this:

```
{{each object.[logitech]}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

I've tried lookup methods such as `.[(lookup @root.brand)]` and `.[(lookup ../@root.brand)]` with no luck so far.

I am able to run an additional conditional; but it's not the ideal solution since I don't know how large of a loop this could be over time.

```
{{each object}}
    {{#compare @key "==" @root.brand}}
        {{@key}}: {{this}}
    {{/compare}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [lookup](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#lookup) is the right approach, but you are not using it correctly. `lookup` takes two parameters, the first is the Object on which to do the lookup and the second is the key. It looks like you are passing only the key.

I think the best approach would be to add a `brands` Object to your root data object, just for clarity as to what Object we want to perform the lookup on. The resulting data Object could look like:

```
{
  "brandId": "logitech",
  "brands": {
    "logitech": {
      "keyOne": "Logitech, Value 1",
      "keyTwo": "Logitech, Value 2",
      "keyThree": "Logitech, Value 3"
    },
    "other": {
      "keyOne": "Brand 2, Value 1",
      "keyTwo": "Brand2, Value 2",
      "keyThree": "Brand2, Value 3"
    }
  }
}
```

This way, every time you call the template, you add for the value `brandId` the key that you want to lookup in the `brands` Object. The template becomes:

```
{{#each (lookup brands @root.brandId)}}
    {{@key}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lna7jx9y/) for your reference.

I feel I should add here that, at the place where you call the template, if you have access to the `brands` Object *and* the desired `brandId`, then you could just do the lookup in code and pass the result to the template. Like:

```
template({ brands[brandId] });
```